# Open 4 web browser windows in full-screen mode each in 1/4 of the screen

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, webcam, fullscreen

I regularly have some webcams open on one of the monitors of my computer. I would like to be able to open them in full screen mode, but have each "full screen" be only 1/4 of the whole screen.

Here's how I view them at present:

[image]

I would like to have each webcam run in full-screen mode so that I get larger pictures and avoid wasting screen space with all the window frames, toolbars, etc.

Is there any way I can do this? My web browser of choice is Google Chrome and I'm using Ubuntu 18.10

NB I have a second monitor connected to my computer too, so any solution needs to take that into consideration too.

Xephyr is a partial solution, but it seems I need to run a new instance of the browser with it's own profile in order to be able to have it display to a separate X display. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197188/can-i-put-multiple-x-windows-into-a-single-larger-window

Comment: You could write a webpage (HTML and CSS) that splits the screen into 4 and displays each of the feeds in it's own quadrant. That would give some extra space to make the videos larger. Getting help with this, however, would be off-topic here as it is a programming question.

Comment: Not a bad idea, worth a try.

Comment: I made a webpage which worked 4-up and 9-up (using Flex layout in CSS3) which was working until the webcams I was viewing disabled embedding their videos.

Answer (score 4):

With [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) that is easily possible.

1. [Install Vivaldi](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-vivaldi-browser-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)
2. Enable Tabgroups in vivaldi://settings/tabs/
   [image: Tabgroups]
3. Open your camera feeds in separate tabs
4. If they all have the same domain just right click one tab and select **Stack Tabs by Host [number of tabs and domain]** if they are not from the same domain just drag and drop them slowly on top of each other until one gets grayed out.
   [image: Stack Tabs]
5. It should look like this now: [image: Stacked Tabs]
6. Tile all four (or more) tabs by an even grid: 
   [image]
7. It should now look like this
   [image: Tiled Tabs]
8. Scale them to size with holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling with your mouse wheel or <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>.

The active Tab is marked by a thin red border and it's URL is displayed in the addressbar.

If you want to, you can press <kbd>F11</kbd> to hide all unnecessary things like addressbar or menu button.

[image: maximized Window]

Comment: You have to drag it so, that the tab you want to stack onto gets greyed out

Comment: @K7AAY It's a bit tricky to get it right at first but you learn how to use it.

Comment: Aha! SLOWLY drag tab Y atop tab X until tab X goes gray.

Comment: Can the stack be set to launch when the browser opens?

Comment: Just allow it to reopen the last used session?

Comment: I'm sure you could do it with a command but I already shut down my PC as I'm going to bed

Comment: I tried Vivaldi and this works, but practically it offers no real improvement vs 4 separate windows in Chrome as the videos still have all the YouTube decorations whereas what I was hoping for was for each video to take up 1/4 (or 1/9) of the screen without wasting space with all the YouTube decorations, scroll bars, etc.